# % of total formula not populating in userform textbox?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Trying to have a text box labeled `txtPercentage` populate a % difference between two text box values `txtCurrentHourly` and `txtNewHourlyRate`. Why is my `txtPercentage` not populating the value when the other objects are triggered?

```
Private Sub txtNewHourly_Change()
Dim a As Double, b As Double
        Dim txtpercent, c
    
        a = txtCurrentHourly.Value
        b = txtNewHourlyRate.Value
        txtpercent = (b - a) / a
        
        If Me.cmbHourlyAnnual.Value = "Hourly" Then
            If b <> 0 Then
                txtpercent
            End If
        ElseIf Me.cmbHourlyAnnual.Value = "Annual" Then
            If b <> 0 Then
                txtpercent
            End If
        End If
        txtPercentage.Value = IIf(IsError(txtpercent), "-", txtpercent)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using `txtPercentage_Change`, if `txtPercentage` is the textbox you want to populate?

Comment: @BigBen i updated my code, but not sure what you're asking? I clicked on view code for the % change text box that I'd like the % diff to populate in, what else should i be doing?

Comment: You're trying to change the `txtPercentage` textbox... but the only way this code would execute is *if `txtPercentage` changes*. That's not the trigger you're looking for.... hint, "when the **other objects** are triggered".

Comment: @BigBen so my new hourly rate is what will change, updated my code, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Is there a new problem now?

Comment: nope, that fixed it! Appreciate the help